# Can a method of an class (in a shared_ptr) be tied to a static function in a traits class?

Tags: c++11, generic-programming

Historically, I've been using trait classes to hold information and apply that into a "generic" function that runs the same "algorithm."  Only differed by the trait class.  For example: https://onlinegdb.com/ryUo7WRmN

```
enum selector { SELECTOR1, SELECTOR2, SELECTOR3, };

// declaration
template < selector T> struct example_trait;

template<> struct example_trait<SELECTOR1> {  
static constexpr size_t member_var = 3;  
static size_t do_something() { return 0; }
};

template<> struct example_trait<SELECTOR2> {  
static constexpr size_t member_var = 5; 
static size_t do_something() { return 0; }  
};


// pretend this is doing something useful but common
template < selector T, typename TT = example_trait<T> > 
void function() { 
std::cout << TT::member_var << std::endl; 
std::cout << TT::do_something() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    function<SELECTOR1>();
    function<SELECTOR2>();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure how to create "generic" algorithms this when dealing with polymorphic classes.

For example: https://onlinegdb.com/S1hFLGC7V

Below I have created an inherited class hierarchy. In this example I have a base catch-all example that defaults all the parameters to something (0 in this case). And then each derived class sets overrides specific methods.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <assert.h>    

using namespace std;

struct Base {
 virtual int get_thing_one() {
     return 0;
    }

 virtual int get_thing_two() {
     return 0;
    }

 virtual int get_thing_three() {
     return 0;
    }

 virtual int get_thing_four() {
     return 0;
    }    
};

struct A : public Base {
    virtual int get_thing_one() override {
     return 1;
    }

  virtual int get_thing_three() override {
     return 3;
 }  
};

struct B : public Base {
    virtual int get_thing_one() override {
     return 2;
    }    

    virtual int get_thing_four() override{
     return 4;
 }    
};
```

Here I created a simple factory, not elegant but for illustrative purposes

```
// example simple factory
std::shared_ptr<Base> get_class(const int input) {
    switch(input)
    {
        case 0:
            return std::shared_ptr<Base>(std::make_shared<A>());
        break;

        case 1:
            return std::shared_ptr<Base>(std::make_shared<B>());
        break;

        default:
            assert(false);
        break;
    }
}
```

So this is the class of interest.  It is a class does "something" with the data from the classes above.  The methods below are a simple addition example but imagine a more complicated algorithm that is very similar for every method.

```
// class that uses the shared_ptr
class setter {
    private:

    std::shared_ptr<Base> l_ptr;

    public:

    setter(const std::shared_ptr<Base>& input):l_ptr(input)
    {}

    int get_thing_a()
    {
        return l_ptr->get_thing_one() +  l_ptr->get_thing_two();
    }

    int get_thing_b()
    {
        return l_ptr->get_thing_three() +  l_ptr->get_thing_four();
    }
};

int main()
{
    constexpr int select = 0;
    std::shared_ptr<Base> example = get_class(select);
    setter l_setter(example);

    std::cout << l_setter.get_thing_a() << std::endl;
    std::cout << l_setter.get_thing_b() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

How can I make the "boilerplate" inside the setter class more generic? I can't use traits as I did in the example above because I can't tie static functions with an object.  So is there a way to make the boilerplate example more common?

Somewhere along the lines of having a selector, say

```
enum thing_select { THINGA, THINGB, };

template < thing_select T >
struct thing_traits;

template <>
struct thing_traits<THINGA>
{
     static int first_function() --> somehow tied to shared_ptr<Base> 'thing_one' method
     static int second_function() --> somehow tied to shared_ptr<Base> 'thing_two' method
}

template <>
struct thing_traits<THINGB>
{
     static int first_function() --> somehow tied to shared_ptr<Base> 'thing_three' method
     static int second_function() --> somehow tied to shared_ptr<Base> 'thing_four' method
}

// generic function I'd like to create
template < thing_select T, typename TT = thing_traits<T> >
int perform_action(...)
{
   return TT::first_function(..) + TT::second_function(..);
}
```

I ideally would like to modify the class above to something along the lines of

```
    // Inside setter class further above
    int get_thing_a()
    {
        return perform_action<THINGA>(...);
    }

    int get_thing_b()
    {
        return perform_action<THINGB>(...);
    }
```

The answer is, maybe I can't, and I need to pass int the shared_ptr as a parameter and call the specific methods I need instead of trying to tie a shared_ptr method to a static function (in hindsight, that doesn't sound like a good idea...but I wanted to bounce my idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoever makes the actual call will need a reference of the object, one way or the other. Therefore, assuming you want `perform_action` to perform the actual call, you will have to pass the parameter.

Now, if you really want to store which function of `Base` to call as a `static` in `thing_traits` without passing a parameter, you can leverage pointer to member functions:

```
template <>
struct thing_traits<THINGA>
{
    static constexpr int (Base::*first_function)() = &Base::get_thing_one;
    ...
}

template < thing_select T,  typename TT = thing_traits<T>>
int perform_action(Base & b)
{
   return (b.*TT::first_function)() + ...;
}
```

You can also play instead with returning a function object that does the call for you (and the inner function takes the parameter).

It all depends on who you need to make the call and what information/dependencies you assume you have available in each class/template.

Comment: Can you provide quick example of returning a function object that does the call?  I'd think that perform_action would have to pass the object anyway that would feed into the function object parameter.

Comment: @user1945925 Are you comfortable using lambdas in C++11? If yes, you simply need to return one from `first_function()`, and then you call the lambda in `perform_action()`. Of course, you need to pass the parameter to the lambda, but you wouldn't need to pass it to `first_function()`.